# How to call a directive from an another directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have just started using AngularJS. Is there a way to use a directive from an another directive ?
I would like to add new `<div time></div>` on click on the parent.

EDIT : **index.html**

```
<div class="time" addtime ng-click="addTime()">
  <!-- ADD NEW <div resizable draggable ...></div> from directive 'time' HERE -->
</div>
```

EDIT : **directive.js**

```
dragDirectives.directive('addtime', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

    },
    controller: function addtimeCtrl($scope, $element){
      $scope.addTime = function() {
        // ADD NEW <div resizable draggable ...></div> from directive 'time'
      };
    }
  }
});

dragDirectives.directive('time', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div resizable draggable class="duree" ng-class="{\'resize-active\': isResizeActive, \'drag-active\': isDragActive }" ng-style="{ width: myWidth, left: myLeft }">',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post example in Fiddle? generally you can use `require: '^parent',` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular you do not do DOM-related or jQuery-ish stuff (i.e. `addEventListener`). The approach would be:

- Have a model describe the `<div time>` elements you have, e.g.:

  ```
  scope.timeElements = [];
  ```
- Itarate over it in the template:

  ```
  <div time ng-repeat="t in timeElements"></div>
  ```
- Handle the event by manipulating the model, e.g.:

  (HTML)

  ```
  <div class="time" addtime ng-click="addTime()">
  ```

  (JS)

  ```
  scope.addTime = function() {
      scope.timeElements.push(something);
  };
  ```

This is only an outline for a real solution, as many details are still missing, but you should get the idea. A fiddle would help getting more specific.

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Comment: Can you check my update please ? I changed my approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
require: '^parent' // a better way to go

dragDirectives.directive('addtime', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div time ng-repeat="t in timeElements"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      scope.timeElements = [1, 2, 3]
    },
    controller: function addtimeCtrl($scope) {
      this.addTime = function() {
        $scope.timeElements.push($scope.timeElements.length + 1);
      };
    }

  }
});

dragDirectives.directive('time', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^addtime',
    template: '<div ng-click="addTime()">time</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      scope.addTime = ctrl.addTime;
    }
  }
});
```